# breeze.plot does not compile but works in REPL

Tags: scala, breeze

I tried the sample code in 
https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Quickstart

It works when I use a scala console, but in the IDE, it gets a compilation error

```
p += plot(x, x :^ 2.0)
```

type mismatch; found : Unit required: breeze.plot.Series

is plot only meant to work in the console? Or is there something I can do to make the code compile?

Comment: Three things: 1) What's `x`? 2) Do you have all necessary Breeze dependencies in the IDE? 3) Are there several methods with the same name that might give conflicts for Tab-completes? Example, Scala has `split` method that might take REGEX `String` or `Char`; if you tab complete on the REGEX one but pass `Char` to it it will compile (since `Char` is a `String` for that purpose) but will not work as desired.

Comment: 1) x is DenseVector.zeros[Double]. 2) in the source, I found plot is not a method but an embedded object   lazy val plot = {
    val rv = new org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot()
    rv.setDomainAxis(xaxis)
    rv.setRangeAxis(yaxis)

    rv.setDrawingSupplier(new DefaultDrawingSupplier(
      Plot.paints,
      Plot.fillPaints,
      Plot.outlinePaints,
      Plot.strokes,
      Plot.outlineStrokes,
      Plot.shapes))

    rv
  }. my scala is not good enough to decipher this beyond this point. I am hoping someone who know Plot can help.